# How to send Bearer Token to different Website without Query String in C#/ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, single-sign-on, owin

SSO/Oauth issue that I'm hoping is either simple, inexperience (probably) or just impossible.

I have Website A and Website B. Website A is under my control, and we currently use OAuth/OWin for SSO. Things work as intended, I can successfully make authentication/bearer tokens, all that jazz. Initially, to allow Website A credentials to be used for Website B, I'd pass the bearer token as a QueryString in the URL. The website would create and get the nessicary bits and bobs to get the Bearer token and stick it in a . User clicks the link, token is there in the URL.

What I'd like to do is take that information out of the QueryString/URL.

I've been looking at Request and Responses, using combinations of HttpWebRequest,  Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(), using Ajax calls to try and call Website B, and I still can't seem to get the token information over, even when I try to just use a dummy Website.

From my research, it seems like the answer is "Encrypt and pass it in a query string" or put it in the Authorization Header. But every example I see, shows that going to a API for validation and not passing it to another website login page. Anyone know any examples? Is this even possible without some weird inbetween?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it from the URL, you'll need to POST the token to Website B from Website A. The location you post to will need to be a server side endpoint that is prepared to look for the token and do something with it. You cannot POST to to a client side HTML page without it being in the URL.

Comment: So here's the thing I don't think I just get. I'd assume I'd need to do sometihng like this for posting the token, correct? `var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
 client.open("POST", "http://WEBSITEB.COM");
  client.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer Meow");
 client.send();`

Comment: Does the other system know what to do with that though? It appears you're posting that on the client side, but it would have to establish a session on their side to associate that bearer token with the user who then is being taken to the site. Normally, the user would be directed to the authentication provider, authenticate with username/password, and receive a token showing they authenticated. After which, they are directed back to the originating application. The application then takes that token and exchanges it for a token that it can use in every request to the server.

Comment: The application is likely stateless, so when the browser sends a request with the authorization header, it only exists for that one request. If you do what you outlined and then redirect the user to Website B, it won't include the bearer token.

Comment: I appreciate the help. :) So, if I'm understanding, this is the general workflow...

`1) User clicks WEBSITE B on WEBSITE A
 2)POST with AUTHHEADER to http://WEBSITEB/CheckFromA
 3) WebsiteB calls A Auth to make sure token is real
 like so.   3a) If(real) 
  match with user on website B
  else
  goto Login Website B`
  
...but if so, then how do I send the Token over? Like 
my comment above or is there another better way C#/JS wise?

Comment: Does it work today with it passed in the QueryString? If so, I might be able to give you a clearer solution.

Comment: Website B's design is still in flux, but yes it does. It currently looks in the Querystring, takes it, and checks it against Website A. Rewriting how Website B catches the token is still up for grabs, but I'm just not sure how to actually do it without putting it in the querystring.

Comment: You could possibly do a simple form post from Website A to Website B. For example, let's say your querystring parameter is named "token". You could put a hidden input on your form that would send this information to website B. It would look something like this: `<html><body><form action='websiteb.com' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='token' value='meow' /><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></form></body></html>`